# Detect incoming call from a GSM modem in c#

Tags: c#, modem

I am developing a C# application to make and receive calls from a GSM modem. I am using a `timer_tick` event to regularly read the port using `port.ReadExisting()` and comparing it with `RING`. If there is a match, display in a label that there is an incoming call. However I couldn't get it to work. Looking for suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to handle a response coming from gsm modem in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447820/how-to-handle-a-response-coming-from-gsm-modem-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @codecaster: yes the ques might be similar. But i gave the approach that i followed, and it is not working. Any other way to deal with it?

Comment: @ShiridishBk - If you want help we need coce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. Cheers. This is the code that i wrote.. Might help some one

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
        if (port.IsOpen)  
        {
           string s = port.ReadExisting();

               if (s.Contains("\r\nRING\r\n"))
               {
                   incall_status.Text = "Incoming Call....";
                   incall_status.Visible = true;
               }
               else if (s.Contains("\r\nNO CARRIER\r\n"))
               {
                   incall_status.Text = "Call Disconnected";
                   bgwrkr_calldisconect.RunWorkerAsync();
               }

        }
    }
```